# how to reload the content of the div block every time the database is updated or inserted

Tags: php, jquery

how to reload the div block every time the database is hit?
 I have tried using the setInterval function, I need to reload the block when the database table is updated or inserted.

Comment: I tried using the setInterval function

Comment: atleast show ur form....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ([AFAIK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK)) impossible to have a purely event-based set-up here. Once the page is loaded the first time, any further dynamic loading must be set up on the client side, and the server itself cannot trigger this behaviour.

Your only solution would be to poll the server at a prescribed interval and reload the data using `JavaScript` (with or without the assistance of jQuery).

`setInterval` would be the obvious choice. You say you've already used this, but give no examples of your code so *why* this isn't working isn't apparent.

For example, if you had a `PHP` page called `data_reload.php` on your server which generated the contents of the `div` you're trying to populate (in `HTML`), you could dynamically update the container with the following (note: assumes jQuery for brevity)

```
// Function that does the actual work of updating the container
function updateContent(jContainer, htmlSource) {
    $.get(htmlSource, function(html) {
        jContainer.html(html);
    });
}

setInterval(function() {
    updateContent($("#data"), 'data_reload.php');
}, 3000); // update every 3 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval` function of javascript and reload the div using jquery `get` or `load` in some time interval

You should specify the content of div in some server page and get the content from there using `get` load `method`

Answer (score 0):

The best possible option for you is use JQuery.

1. Try to create  a function in jquery such that whenever a database is updated/changed the function is activated.
2. Now call the div block using its id. and use show /hide to display and hide it for the user.

Next time while posting a question try to post the code that you have tried, it becomes easy for us to debug.

Comment: How can you do the first thing that you mentioned ?

Comment: you access db by clicking a button or how?? try to post ur code or try something